# Send email from Gmail to localhost (Postfix)

Tags: email, gmail, postfix-mta

I need to send email from Gmail to my local machine with Postfix. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send email from an external mail server to your email server this is what you do:

1. Get a public IP address to your mail server.
2. Get a domain name for sending the incoming email. Let us call it `yourdomain.com`.
3. Map `MX` entry for your domain `yourdomain.com` to the public IP address of your mail server. `MX` entries publish your domain's mail server location so that a mail server like gmail can find our where the email should be sent.

With this setup any email sent to a valid user on your mail server using email address like `user@yourdomain.com` should reach your server.